# Use Hampton Bay in wall ceiling fan remote with Harbor Breeze fan?

Tags: lighting, switch, ceiling-fan, installation

Edit

I have a Harbor Breeze fan that I lost the remote to. I bought a universal remote that Hampton Bay makes (advertised to work with any fan according to an employee) that can be mounted in a wall plate yet doesn't require wires to the fan and runs off of batteries. The issue is that the Hampton Bay remote uses dip switches and the Harbor Breeze fan uses "smart pairing" by hitting a learn button on a remote.  I looked through both of the manuals and I couldn't find anything helpful in either one.  Is there anyway to get this remote to work with my fan or do I have to find another one? 
Fan: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Harbor-Breeze-Merrimack-52-in-Antique-Bronze-Indoor-Outdoor-Downrod-Mount-Ceiling-Fan-with-Light-Kit-and-Remote/4165863 
Remote: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Ceiling-Fan-Wall-Control-9050H/202801200?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CTHD%7CG%7C0%7CG-BASE-PLA-D27L-CeilingFans%7C&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI2p_43OGR1gIVAotpCh06OQMQEAQYASABEgIcqfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=CIuSn-DhkdYCFUa1swodBC4Ipg

Answer (score 2):

The switch comes with the fan control you need. You have to replace the fancontrol from the fan with it. I'll include a pic highlighting the part I talking about.[image]